# Meteor aggregate group by the month on Date.now() property value

Tags: meteor

A Meteor server code tries to group documents by the month. So that the count of all the documents in each month is given.
The documents have `createdAt = Date.now();` property and meteorhacks:aggregate
 is installed. Any Suggestions? thx

What I considered:
1) Transform the collection adding new property `MMYYYY: 6-digit-number' and group by that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your consideration is a good one if you plan to aggregate often.  It would certainly be faster if you wrote a year and month string in the doc when you create it. Keep in mind that you will have to remember to keep those strings up to date if you modify the corresponding date field.

If you won't be aggregating very often, then it's probably not worth the effort. Just convert your epoch time values to new Date objects and leverage the Date aggregation operators in your aggregation pipeline.  Here is an example.

```
var Metrics = new Mongo.Collection('metrics');

Metrics.aggregate([
  {$project: {
    createdAtDate: { $add: [new Date(0), "$createdAt"] }
  }},
  {$project : {
     year : {$year : "$createdAtDate"}, 
     month : {$month : "$createdAtDate"}
  }},
  {$group : {
     _id : {year : "$year", month : "$month"}, 
     count : {$sum : 1}
  }}
]);
```

If you go with a date string (where the document field called "createdAtString" is MMYYYY) then your pipeline would look like this instead.

```
var Metrics = new Mongo.Collection('metrics');

Metrics.aggregate([
  {$group : {
     _id : "$createdAtString", 
     count : {$sum : 1}
  }}
]);
```

Comment: Using the first formate, a server error saying "MongoError: can't convert from BSON type NumberDouble to Date"

Comment: @FredJ. It sounds like you have one or more documents in yiur collection with a createdAt value that is not a date object. Can you verify that all documents have a true date for createdAt in your collection

Comment: As my question stated, all the createdAt have been created with `Date.now()` which is epoch time.

Comment: How would a match criteria can be added? like say property `x = 'john'` or `userId = this.userId`...

Comment: @FredJ. Add a [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/) aggregation operator in your pipeline array in index 0 that contains your filter selectors